# Ant Build File Migrate Doctrine (asking for yes/no)

Tags: php, ant, doctrine-orm, jenkins, zend-framework2

So I have this target in my ant build file:

```
<target name="migrate" description="Migrate the database">
    <exec executable="${basedir}/vendor/bin/doctrine-module" failonerror="true">
        <arg line="migrations:migrate"/>
    </exec>
</target>
```

The doctrine migrate command is asking a question and expecting yes or no answer before it runs though. So my build fails:

```
richard@richard-desktop:~/projects/myproject$ ant migrate
Buildfile: /home/richard/projects/myproject/build.xml

migrate:
     [exec]                                                            
     [exec]                     Doctrine Migrations                    
     [exec]                                                            
     [exec] 
     [exec] 
     [exec] 
     [exec]                       
     [exec]   [RuntimeException]  
     [exec]   Aborted             
     [exec]                       
     [exec] 
     [exec] 
     [exec] migrations:migrate [--write-sql] [--dry-run] [--configuration[="..."]] [--db-configuration[="..."]] [version]
     [exec] 
     [exec] 
     [exec] WARNING! You are about to execute a database migration that could result in schema changes and data lost. Are you sure you wish to continue? (y/n)

BUILD FAILED
/home/richard/projects/myproject/build.xml:42: exec returned: 1

Total time: 0 seconds
richard@richard-desktop:~/projects/myproject$
```

How can I make ant automatically answer yes to that question so it runs the migration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was actually very easy:

```
<target name="migrate" description="Migrate the database">
    <exec executable="${basedir}/vendor/bin/doctrine-module" failonerror="true">
        <arg line="migrations:migrate --no-interaction"/>
    </exec>
</target>
```